Extract bordering countries from image using Python
I have maps which look like this with colored countries and black borders.
I need a way to extract all neighbouring countries (blue) for every country on the map (red).
The result should look like this:
{
    "country1":{
        "neighbours":["country2","country3","country4","country5","country6","country7","country8"]
    },
    "country2":{
        "neighbours":["country1","country8","country9","country10"]
    },
...
}

So far I have converted it to vector (.svg) using potrace and PIL as suggested to make the map easier to work with this result (An image of the SVG file. I can't upload SVG.)
import os
from PIL import Image

threshold = 620

file_in = "/Users/nils/Documents/map.png"
img = Image.open(file_in)
pixels = list(img.getdata())

newPixels = []
for pixel in pixels:
    if pixel[0]+pixel[1]+pixel[2] <= threshold:
        newPixel = (0, 0, 0)
    else:
        newPixel = (255, 255, 255)
    newPixels.append(newPixel)

newImg = Image.new(img.mode, img.size)
newImg.putdata(newPixels)

file_out = "test.bmp"
print (len(newImg.split()))  # test
if len(newImg.split()) == 4:
    print("converting")
    r, g, b, a = newImg.split()
    newImg = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
    newImg.save(file_out)
else:
    newImg.save(file_out)
    
    
os.system("potrace test.bmp --svg -o my.svg")


How do you know country name from image?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

real world map? the data exists already: both the adjacency matrix, as well as vector data of all the borders, so you can calculate the adjacency yourself. -- not a real world map? then you better have vector data of the borders. if you don't have that vector data, your first task is to obtain that.

No, I will not use a real world map. The current image is just an example. @alderven the country names are not important for me an id would be enough.
I can later add the country names manually.

@christoph-rackwitz I have now converted it to .eps

I appreciate the effort. however, that type of result is not going to lead to a solution (it's got defects such as gaps). you'll need to "vectorize" the data differently.you need to extract connected components of uniform coloring. that should stop each component at any borders that surround it. -- your pictures are very low resolution. they're downscaled in fact, because the borders aren't just faint but literally blurred from downscaling. is that the data you expect to work on, or will you work on better data?

I am gonna work with Better Data in higher resolution. We are currently still working on the maps so we can still make it higher resolution (which we will). I know that I need to extract areas instead of lines though I have not found any tool supporting this with python.

let me clarify: the resolution itself is secondary. the quality of the lines/edges is crucial. they should be "clear enough". this picture you provided looks pretty close to ideal. threshold it, run connected components labeling, now you've got components. then you "just" need to determine neighbor relationships. I once did that with dilation, of each component's mask, and then intersecting those masks.

here's a little preview of what I think is doable: https://i.imgur.com/OGmofiu.png (label 0 is borders, label 1 is non-africa = sea and other continents)

you might be able to help the reopening along with some improvements to the question. the PIL+potrace code is secondary (irrelevant). you could present an attempt that involves converting to grayscale, thresholding (level 192), and connected component labeling. I'd recommend not having any loops that touch individual pixels. at the very least, numpy can operate on entire arrays at once.

First the source image, second an illustration of the resulting graph (click them):


The approach:

Thresholding, to get one connected component per country
Connected Components Labeling
For each component:

Dilate enough to reach across border lines and overlap with neighbors
Intersect
Collect the labels in that intersection
Collect those relationships



import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = cv.imread("7oPxiEBe.png")
(height, width) = im.shape[:2]

gray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

(th, mask) = cv.threshold(gray, 192, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

This picture looks like black lines on white background but you should see it as white blobs on black background:

# remove small components
# near egypt, the borders enclose 1-2 pixel sized components of sea

(num_labels, labels, stats, centroids) = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask, connectivity=4)
for i in range(num_labels):
    if stats[i, cv.CC_STAT_AREA] <= 2:
        mask[labels == i] = 0


# the actual labeling
(num_labels, labels, stats, centroids) = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask, 8, cv.CV_32S)

# calculate a central point for each component
# that's just for visualization

# give the "sea" label a border so its central point doesn't stick to a corner of the picture
modified_mask = mask.copy()
modified_mask[:,0] = 0
modified_mask[:,-1] = 0
modified_mask[0,:] = 0
modified_mask[-1,:] = 0
dist = cv.distanceTransform(modified_mask, cv.DIST_L2, cv.DIST_MASK_PRECISE)

central_points = []
for label in range(num_labels):
    component_dist = np.where(labels == label, dist, 0)
    (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv.minMaxLoc(component_dist)
    central_points.append(maxLoc)

central_points = np.array(central_points)


# now let's establish neighbor relationships
# for each component mask,
#   dilate the component mask by a few pixels,
#   calculate intersection with (original mask - component mask)
#   collect the labels in the intersection
#   own label might show up, shouldn't (assertion). any collected labels are neighbors.

adjacency = np.zeros((num_labels, num_labels), dtype=bool)

# label 0 (borders): neighbor to everyone, that's useless
# label 1 (sea/background): neighbor to coastal countries
for label in range(num_labels):
    if label == 0: continue # borders themselves
    # if label == 1: continue # non-continent (sea, other continents)

    component = (labels == label)
    noncomponent = mask.astype(bool) & ~component
    dilated_component = cv.dilate(component.astype(np.uint8), kernel=None, iterations=3).astype(bool)
    # NOTE: iterations=1 gives nothing, 2 gives *something* but with obvious missing edges.
    intersection = noncomponent & dilated_component

    neighbor_labels = np.unique(labels[intersection])
    adjacency[label, neighbor_labels] = True
    print(f"neighbors of {label:2d}: {set(neighbor_labels)}")

neighbors of  1: {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 43, 44, 47, 48, 50, 52}
neighbors of  2: {1, 3, 5}
neighbors of  3: {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11}
neighbors of  4: {1, 3, 7, 8, 9}
neighbors of  5: {1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 12, 13}
neighbors of  6: {1, 13, 5}
neighbors of  7: {8, 4}
neighbors of  8: {1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 15}
neighbors of  9: {8, 4}
neighbors of 10: {3, 8, 11, 15, 16, 22, 31}
neighbors of 11: {3, 5, 10, 12, 16, 19, 20, 24}
neighbors of 12: {5, 11, 13, 20, 30}
neighbors of 13: {1, 5, 6, 12, 14, 17, 25, 30}
neighbors of 14: {1, 13, 17, 23}
neighbors of 15: {1, 8, 10, 18, 21, 22}
neighbors of 16: {10, 11, 24, 28, 29, 31}
neighbors of 17: {34, 13, 14, 23, 25, 26, 27}
neighbors of 18: {1, 15}
neighbors of 19: {24, 1, 11, 20}
neighbors of 20: {1, 37, 38, 39, 11, 12, 19, 30}
neighbors of 21: {1, 22, 15}
neighbors of 22: {32, 1, 33, 10, 15, 21, 31}
neighbors of 23: {1, 27, 14, 17}
neighbors of 24: {1, 11, 16, 19, 29}
neighbors of 25: {34, 35, 36, 13, 17, 30}
neighbors of 26: {1, 34, 27, 17}
neighbors of 27: {1, 26, 17, 23}
neighbors of 28: {16, 1, 29, 31}
neighbors of 29: {16, 1, 28, 24}
neighbors of 30: {35, 37, 12, 13, 20, 25}
neighbors of 31: {1, 33, 10, 16, 22, 28}
neighbors of 32: {1, 22, 33}
neighbors of 33: {32, 1, 22, 31}
neighbors of 34: {1, 36, 40, 17, 25, 26}
neighbors of 35: {1, 36, 37, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 25, 30}
neighbors of 36: {34, 35, 40, 41, 25}
neighbors of 37: {1, 35, 39, 43, 20, 30}
neighbors of 38: {1, 20, 39}
neighbors of 39: {1, 20, 37, 38}
neighbors of 40: {1, 34, 35, 36, 41, 42, 45, 46, 47}
neighbors of 41: {40, 42, 35, 36}
neighbors of 42: {40, 41, 35}
neighbors of 43: {1, 35, 37}
neighbors of 44: {1, 50, 35, 45}
neighbors of 45: {35, 40, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51}
neighbors of 46: {40, 45, 47}
neighbors of 47: {1, 40, 45, 46, 49, 52, 53}
neighbors of 48: {1}
neighbors of 49: {51, 52, 45, 47}
neighbors of 50: {1, 44, 45, 51, 52}
neighbors of 51: {49, 50, 52, 45}
neighbors of 52: {1, 47, 49, 50, 51, 53, 54}
neighbors of 53: {52, 47}
neighbors of 54: {52}

# illustration
scale = 4
canvas = cv.resize((im >> 1), dsize=None, fx=scale, fy=scale, interpolation=cv.INTER_NEAREST)
for i in range(2, num_labels):
    for j in range(i+1, num_labels):
        if adjacency[i, j]:
            #cv.line(canvas, tuple(central_points[i]), tuple(central_points[j]), (0, 255, 0), 1)
            cv.line(
                img=canvas,
                pt1=((central_points[i]+0.5) * scale).astype(int),
                pt2=((central_points[j]+0.5) * scale).astype(int),
                #color=(186, 186, 186),
                color=(255, 255, 255),
                thickness=1,
                lineType=cv.LINE_AA
            )
for i in range(2, num_labels):
    cv.putText(
        img=canvas,
        text=f"{i}",
        org=((central_points[i]+0.5) * scale).astype(int),
        fontFace=cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontScale=0.5 * scale, color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=round(1 * scale)
    )



The adjacency computation method you use avoids an explicit loop over pixels in Python code, but is very inefficient, and scales badly with the number of regions. I would use dip. RegionAdjacencyGraph() instead. It does a single scan through the image. It does require the lines between regions to be exactly 1 pixel thick, or for the regions to be touching. The latter is easy to accomplish by just dilating the label image by two pixels.

I might give diplip a look now. was meaning to for a while.

Thank you so much

I have just tried it. It works perfectly with the map. Thanks so much! I dont know what I would have done without your help!
